# Where to check whether a package is shipped with the JRE for Java

Tags: java

I'm using javax.xml.soap package in my java desktop application and I would like to check whether that package (and more in general any package shipped with JDK) is available in JRE's on different platforms (win, mac, linux) for deployment.
The aim is to make sure that my application will run on target machines with JRE or check if full JDK is required. Also for linux I would like to make sure that the open-jdk jre 1.6 (not the oracle one) will be enough.
Thanks

Comment: `Class.forName(someClass)` and wait for the ClassNotFoundException...

Comment: Sorry perhaps my question was not clear enough. I'm looking for documentation saying whether a certain package is available on JRE or requires JDK before deploying my application. I would like to avoid packaging my application and testing on a JRE only equipped target machine to see if that package / class exists.

Comment: You can always peek in the rt.jar of the JRE shipped with your JDK... They are .zip files after all.

Comment: Great! that's just what I was looking for

Comment: @Iviggiani: Summarized my comments in an answer for future readers of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wan't to find out if a class is included in the JRE you have, do the following:

- Locate the `rt.jar` of your JRE, mine was at `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_07/jre/lib/rt.jar`
- Open it with your favorite `.zip` viewer
- Search for the wanted classes
- You're done!

If you wan't to find out if the JRE you're running at contains your class, do the following:

- Call `Class.forName` with the classname of the class you wan't to test
- Put this in a try-catch-block
- If you catch a `ClassNotFoundException`, its not there!
- Note that this does not state if it is in the default library, just that is is on the classpath!

Answer (score 0):

Ways to guess whether there's a package present in the JVM in runtime:

- Check the JRE version system property (`java.version`)
- Try to load the classes you're expecting in `javax.xml.soap` using [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)

In practice, I'd however rather demand certain JRE(s) to be used to run my application in my system requirements, rather than just trying to detect whether a package is available.

Comment: Sorry perhaps my question was not clear enough. I'm looking for documentation saying whether a certain package is available on JRE or requires JDK before deploying my application. I would like to avoid packaging my application and testing on a JRE only equipped target machine to see if that package / class exists.

Comment: So you are not trying to achieve this programmatically but by reading the docs. You have too google it.

Comment: In general I'd say you won't need JDK unless you want to use any of the development tools (say, javac). All the runtime packages are a part of the JRE, or are some 3rd-party libraries or perhaps some Oracle add-ons (JavaMail is an example). I have no experience with JDK other than Oracle's and IBM's though. It might well be some are packaged differently. If I had to support them, I'd resort to guessing as described in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This effort on portability is very good!
I would suggest you requiring Java 7 because OpenJDK7 is the default implementation for it, so no more "oracle java is better than openjdk".
I think requiring Java 7 is better than requiring a specific Java implementation (Oracle) or "checking if it runs on openjdk 6".
Anyways I'd suggest david's points!